# Uninstall conda without using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I messed up my conda installation and now there is no file named python in anaconda3/bin directory.

```
$ conda info -a
/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda: line 2: /home/username/anaconda3/bin/python: No such file or directory

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

When I enter the anaconda3/bin directory I can see the following files:

```
$ ls | grep python
ipython3.c~
ipython.c~
python3.9.c~
python3.9-config.c~
python3.c~
python3-config.c~
python.c~
```

I want to uninstall conda and start over but I can not use conda to install anaconda-clean with which I could uninstall conda. How can I uninstall conda completely to get rid of all inconsistencies and problems I created?

Comment: Have you tried the [simple remove from the docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/#simple-remove)?

Comment: you should just be able to delete the whole directory `/home/username/anaconda3/`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I run "rm -rf anaconda3" but the command runs since 10 minutes and when I check the directory size from a differnt terminal with du -s anaconda3 the size of the directory doesn't change.